# Find product of integers at interval of X and update value at position 'i' in an array for N queries

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have given an array of integers of length up to `10^5` & I want to do following operation on array.

1-> Update value of array at any position `i` . `(1 <= i <= n)`

2-> Get products of number at indexes `0, X, 2X, 3X, 4X....`  `(J * X <= n)`

Number of operation will be up to `10^5`.

Is there any `log n` approach to answer query and update values.

Comment: Problem is quite interesting but please show your attempt.

Comment: Sorry I can't get any thing better than brute force.

Comment: Is this an online judge / ACM like problem? Not sure about operation 2, but it sounds like segment tree may suit you

Comment: Yes it is an online judge problem.I thought of segment tree but didn't get logic for implementing it through segment tree.

Comment: Can u share the original problem link?

Comment: Sorry but i can't share problem link here. You can ask me for more details.

Comment: is the problem from ongoing contest? if so, please refrain from posting/asking for a solution before the contest is over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Original thought is to use Segment Tree but I think that it is not needed...)

Let `N = 10^5, A:= original array of size N`

We use 0-based notation when we saying indexing below

Make a new array `B` of integers which of length up to `M = NlgN` :

First integer is equal to `A[0]`;

Next N integers is of index 1,2,3...N of `A`;   I call it group 1

Next N/2 integers is of index 2,4,6....;  I call it group 2

Next N/3 integers 3,6,9....   I call it group 3

Here is an example of visualized `B`:

`B = [A[0] | A[1], A[2], A[3], A[4] | A[2], A[4] | A[3] | A[4]]`

---

I think the original thoughts can be used **without** even using **Segment Tree**..
(It is overkill when you think for operation 2, we always will query specific range on `B` instead of any range, i.e. we do not need that much flexibility and complexity to maintain the data structure)

You can create the new array `B` described above, also create another array `C` of length `M`, `C[i] := products of Group i`

For operation 1 simply use `O(# factors of i)` to see which Group(s) you need to update, and update the values in both `B` and `C`  (i.e.  `C[x]/old B[y] *new B[y]`)

For operation 2 just output corresponding `C[i]`

Not sure if I was wrong but this should be even faster and should pass the judge, if the original idea is correct but got TLE

---

As OP has added a new condition: for operation 2, we need to multiply A[0] as well, so we can special handle it. Here is my thought:

Just declare a new variable `z = A[0]`, for operation 1, if it is updating index 0, update this variable; for operation 2, query using the same method above, and multiply by `z` afterwards.

I have updated my answer so now I simply use the first element of `B` to represent `A[0]`

**Example**

```js
A = {1,4,6,2,8,7}


B = {1 | 4,6,2,8,7 | 6,8 | 2 | 8 | 7 }  // O(N lg N)


C = {1 | 2688 | 48 | 2 | 8 | 7 } // O (Nlg N)

factorization for all possible index X (X is the index, so <= N) // O(N*sqrt(N)) 


opeartion 1:

update A[4] to 5: factors = 1,2,4  // Number of factors of index, ~ O(sqrt(N))
which means update Group 1,2,4   i.e. the corresponding elements in B & C

to locate the corresponding elements in B & C maybe a bit tricky, 
but that should not increase the complexity

B = {1 | 4,6,2,5,7 | 6,5 | 2 | 5 | 7 }    // O(sqrt(N))
C = {1 | 2688 | 48/8*5 | 2 | 8/8*5 | 7 }  // O(sqrt(N))


update A[0] to 2:
B = {2 | 4,6,2,5,7 | 6,5 | 2 | 5 | 7 }  // O(1)
C = {2 | 2688/8*5 | 48/8*5 | 2 | 8/8*5 | 7 }  // O(1)



// Now A is actually {2,4,6,2,5,7}

operation 2:

X = 3
C[3] * C[0] = 2*2 = 4  // O(1)


X = 2
C[2] * C[0] = 30*2 = 60  // O(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i applied same logic. It is not sufficient to pass the test. If I update on index 1 it will take N time to update so in worst case it will take N*Q time.

Comment: why update on index 1 will take N time? index 1 should only update group 1...1 has only one factor...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention 0 in question.

Comment: how about special handle index 0? Declare a separate special variable for it's value,  for operation 1 you  update this variable, for operation 2 you do the same as above and multiply by this value?

Comment: In you edit part precomputing will take at most 1700000 steps. Now updating Array C for any X will cost "total number of multiples of X in 1 to X" which is quite high or we can say order of N.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you said...I've added an example, which part did I do wrong?  Or you can just post your original online judge link here, I will try to get AC and explain in detail

Comment: @shole Please include some code snippet. Also what is the role of array B here ?

Comment: @VivekPuri I use array B to maintain the current value of array A, so that when operation 1 incoming, I can use this information to update array C, then update array B itself